# Bug in Yearling badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I was looking at the badges when I noticed that a good number of the recent ones were the Yearling one. I checked them and found that many of them were awarded to people for the n-th time, which is correct according to the badge description:

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. This badge can be awarded multiple times.

From that description, I would understand if a user gets the badge after 12 or more months (once every year if you make 200+ points, or whenever you get 200 points after more than 365 days), but there would not be a possible way of getting it more than once a calendar year. Something like [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=732379), that has been getting the badge every year on the same day for four years:

[image: chooban's Yearling badges]

---

But then, looking at the dates in which the badge was awarded, there are things that do not make sense. Many of them have been awarded and there's not a year between the dates. For example:

- [This user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=98509) got it 6 times in 3 years (once in 2012, twice in 2013 and 2014, and once more in 2015).
- [This other user](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=1156761) got it 4 months ago and today again.
- And like that, [there](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=2335982) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=732407) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=277371) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=312019) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=164861).

**Is there a bug in the way the badge is awarded?**

Comment: You can also get it "unexpectedly" if you merge accounts, an old one merged into a new one, as your "start" date is the old account, so your anniversary changes.

Comment: It's even worse on meta, due to the meta SE spinoff.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=103167

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**NOTE** - After writing the question I realized how the Yearling badge is awarded: you get it once for every year that you've been a member and you have more than 200 * Number_of_years of reputation. Independently of when that reputation was earned, or when you got the previous Yearling badge, which is counter-intuitive as it leads to things like this:

[image: tag award times]

Which, in my opinion, makes no sense at all given the badge description: the member was not active for 3 years (2009-2012), and then got the Yearling badge 3 times in less than 11 months (Nov'12-Oct'13).

Maybe the badge description should be updated to make it more accurate. Or the criteria for obtaining it should be changed to fit the current description.

Here's an illustration of the timing for badges based on [avsej's reputation graph on SE](https://stackexchange.com/users/34826/avsej?tab=reputation)

[image: reputation over time]
Detailed explanation of all badges including Yearling can be found on main meta - [What are the badges I can earn on each site, and what are the exact criteria for earning each badge?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188731#188731), following excerpt explains multiple badges in the same year:

> If at any point you qualify for this year’s badge, you will receive all badges you had previously missed up until this year whenever the script runs again.

Comment: Making the badge care about history is probably a non-starter, since the current criteria are very easy to check.  It could probably be reworded, though.  Are you sure this belongs here, and not on Meta.SE?

Comment: Is there a way of exporting the post to Meta.SE? Or just create a new one there?

Comment: @Kevin, site issues are always appropriate here if they occured while using the site.  The mods will migrate to Meta.SE if they see fit.

Comment: I think there's no need to move it. I went to Meta.SE, searched for a similar question, and [this is a _known thing_ since 2011](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104465/two-yearling-badges-on-the-same-day). The comments have a good [link to how the badges algorithm works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188731#188731). I guess next time I'll search in both meta sites before posting.

Comment: So you get the badge every 200 reputation? This isn't making much sense...

Comment: @Zizouz212 more or less, you get it for every 200 reputation but only once per year that you have been a member. For example, right now you have 852 reputation, and you joined on November'14, so you will get one in Nov'15, then three more in Nov'16, Nov'17 and Nov'18... even if you don't do anything between now and 2018. The same thing happens the other way around: if a person joins SO today but is inactive until 2020 when he/she makes 1,000 points in a a week, then that user will get 5 Yearling badges in that week

Comment: I've been a member for 3,5 years, and recently passed 600 in rep. I got the yearling badge again, but I wrongfully assumed it was because I joined another SE forum yesterday. This clears things up!

Comment: May I ask a question: from 1 to 1000 reputation I earned 5 yearling badges but from 1000 to 1200 I did not earn this badge? why?

Comment: @AmiraliEricJanani You've been in the site for 5 years and 9 months. You will get the badge when you hit the 6 year mark.