# I've earned four "Yearling" badges in the past 48 hours

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, yearling-badge

On Meta Stack Overflow, I received the "Yearling" badge four times in the past 48 hours:

[image]

Comment: Weird. Had you gotten the Yearling badge last year or the year before?

Comment: Although probably a coincidence, but you seem to have currently 800 reputation, which is 200 X 4 ... could this be related to the issue?

Comment: See this one: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291925/bug-in-yearling-badge?rq=1

Comment: A developer was refactoring/tweaking some code surrounding reputation earlier today, and possibly broke it. So yeah, this is a bug; several people got erroneously awarded badges. I believe the incorrect changes were reverted, but erroneously awarded badges were not (have not yet been?) removed. Although this is the first instance I've seen of *multiple* badges being awarded. Congratulations! :-)

Comment: @CodyGray it's not a bug -> see my answer

Comment: There is another explanation.  They lost of server a couple of weeks ago.  Replacing and re-initializing it did not go well, it generated a bunch of notifications for old events.  Getting them now might be explained by the badge being awarded only once a year.  Don't worry about it, you have as many as you should.

Comment: It seems [you just "joined" MSO yesterday (first time accessing MSO?)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2339972/dev-perfecular?tab=activity) and the system checked for the badge. FWIW, [it's awarded 1 per hour for 4 times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=2339972)

Comment: Pretty sure Hans' explanation is correct here. @CodyGray is also right in the sense that all that happened yesterday, but your account wasn't affected by that issue.

Comment: @CodyGray: this user visited MSO for the first time yesterday. This is not a bug, it's part of the normal badge rewarding for new users on Meta.

Comment: More like "bug by design", then. If you've never been to Meta, you probably shouldn't be getting badges for being an "active member" there. If we're going to keep Meta badges separate, then it would make sense for them to be, well, separate. But yes, Adam already disproved my initial hypothesis; I only kept it to prevent destroying the flow of discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @TamásG pointed out in a comment, also given that you currently have 801+ reputation, and that you have been member of SE for 5+ years you case most probably is the same as [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291925/bug-in-yearling-badge?rq=1) question.

Reading the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/188731#188731) we can see that:

> ...If at any point you qualify for this year’s badge, you will receive **all badges you had previously missed up** until this year **whenever the script runs again**.

So this could be one reason you got those badges, as it seem this year you have gained more rep that others.

**Edit:** Further reading the badge list we can see that this is also stated as requirement for earning the badge:

> Have a reputation of at least (number of years since registration) × 200 + 1 (starting reputation)

Considering this statement, you most probably should *not* have earned those badges, as you would need (5+ years) x 200 + 1 = 1001 reputation to qualify for it. Given this it seems that it could be indeed a bug of some sort.

Comment: totally I have 4 yearling badges for now.

Comment: In any case, I believe that if you get more than 1001 reputation (actually a bit more, as you have more than 5 years) you would have been awarded all those badges (5 in that case) as stated in the first quote of my answer.

Comment: This doesn't seem right.  The OP does qualify for 4 Yearling badges, but they shouldn't have been awarded all of them recently.  Their profile shows that their rep has pretty much evenly increased over time since they joined over 4 years ago; they should've had most of those Yearling badges before this recent event.

Comment: @Nat possibly, another thing to notice is that the missing badges are awarded *"whenever the script runs again"*, so that could also be part of the issue

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug. You qualify for a badge when you have 200 per year. You have over 800 rep and you're a member for more than 4 years, so you deserve 4 badges. You were awarded all badges that you have previously missed up:

> If at any point you qualify for this year’s badge, you will receive all badges you had previously missed up until this year whenever the script runs again.

[List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Comment: [The asker's reputation plot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2339972/dev-perfecular?tab=topactivity) shows that they qualified for 3 Yearling badges over a year ago.  So while it looks like they just broke 800 Rep, qualifying for a fourth Yearling badge, the other three shouldn't be recent.