# Is there a problem with the Badge system right now?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

Yesterday I seem to have been awarded the Yearling badge 10 times here on Meta Stack Overflow!
We all love birthdays, but I'd rather keep it to one year at a time!

Is there a bug with the badge system?

Or is there a bug with the messaging system that sent me 10 messages to my inbox about the yearling badge?

Comment: Did you perhaps earn it on multiple different sites in the StackExchange network at the same time? I had this happen somewhat recently and was initially confused myself.

Comment: Considering your account is 10 years old, perhaps a glitch happened? Or a recent login, etc

Comment: Hmm...I haven't contributed to the StackExchange network but I believe I'm a member. Let me check: I just checked. I primarily post on StackOverflow. I'm not active on the rest of the StackExchange network other than viewing.

Comment: @Frinavale It's not a messaging system issue, you did legitimately get the badge 10 times in the span 5 hours

Comment: @NickA haha! Ok so yeah, I've been an active member for 10 years. Maybe they just forgot to issue them over the years. Weird.

Comment: @Frinavale Interestingly it was awardedly correctly on main, it's only on meta SO that you've just been awarded all the badges... presumably because you're new to meta

Comment: Yearling badge is linked to a certain amount of rep. You will only get those badges when you surpass that threshold and then get the badge for all active years, even when you didn't had the rep at that time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bug in Yearling badge?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291925/bug-in-yearling-badge)

Comment: @Tom Not relevant

Comment: @Tom No this still doesn't make sense. There are a good number of my answers that feed into my reputation that I'm sure give me more than 200 a year. And I log in a few times a year too so it's not like I've been completely inactive for over a year.

Comment: @Ivar I have a feeling you are right. I was not on meta before and just checked it out yesterday. This is probably the reason.

Comment: @Tom I'm gonna say no, because this is a fun and interesting meta-specific situation. :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope! Nothing wrong here!

We don't create a meta profile for users until they actually visit meta. We base meta yearling badges on reputation earned on the main site. But, we also seem to consider site membership, even on meta, to be the day they joined the main site. This isn't usually noticed because it's pretty rare for someone to have an profile on the site for ten years before they visit meta for the first time (while logged in). It seems you did that!

So, while you earned them on a gradual schedule [on the main site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=140420):

[image: Screenshot of user's yearling badge award schedule on Stack Overflow]

You earned them all at once when you [joined meta yesterday](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=140420):

[image: Screenshot of user's yearlign badge award schedule on Meta Stack Overflow]

So, welcome to Meta Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 3):

This is the first time you've been active on Meta SO. You *already* had 10 badges on Stack Overflow (the badges dating back to 2010), as can be seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=140420).

We can assume (due to the presence of your New Contributor icon) that you're new to meta participation and so all of the badges were (semi-)simultaneously awarded on meta, as can be seen [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=140420).