# What is meant by ‘active member’ in the description of the Yearling badge?

Tags: support, badges, yearling-badge

The description for the [Yearling](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling) badge, states the following:

> Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation.

What are the conditions for a user to qualify as an “active member”?

While [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291925/bug-in-yearling-badge) explains the Badge can be awarded multiple times per year once a user is considered "active", it doesn't clarify what exactly constitutes "activity" for the purposes of this badge.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat No, I just want to know the conditions for a user to be considered an active member. I am not asking about any bugs

Comment: So what about the linked duplicate  suggestion, that tells you that, didn't answer your question?

Comment: @dinux the answer to that question explains how the Yearling badge is awarded.

Comment: Remember if you are in a union not using the active member may result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @user4581301 I don’t get what you mean. What do you mean by ‘not in a union’?

Comment: @Dinux [c++ humour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union).

Comment: Looking at the proposed duplicate, I cannot - after 2 minutes of looking through the post - find any answer to this question. If you guys just like to clown around, at least provide a quote or anything that helps to find the answer.

Comment: @Cuzy the answer there lists the criteria for getting the badge, nothing else is required to be considered "active", it also links to an MSE answer which describes the criteria in even more detail.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply creating an account on a site will count as being “active” for the purposes of the badge, as long as you earn 200 reputation points per badge.

No other action is required. Passive "reputation income" can provide the necessary "proof of life".

Once an account on a site is created, one will continue to accrue Yearling badges every year, as long as you earn 200 reputation points by any means (per badge).

The reputation does not have to be gained on any given timeframe. One can be "inactive" for several years, then earn whatever multiple of badges that amount of reputation allows.

Simply put, the maximum amount of Yearling badges is the amount of years since the site account creation, and reputation / 200 (rounded down). Whichever is lower.

Comment: You don't even need to sign in, for example here's a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53114/gumbo) whose last seen is more tha 6 years ago but they've [gotten the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=53114) for these years regardles.

Comment: Thanks @Abdul, I thought otherwise, but I was obviously mistaken.

Comment: This is not quite correct, you _also_ need to earn 200 rep per badge earned. "Active" is describing the property of 'doing something to earn 200 rep'. Somewhat ironically on popular sites you can earn passive rep at that amount every _day_ if you are, say, Jon Skeet. It's not a very good formula (it doesn't date-bind the rep gained); it is just `(n*200)` where `n` is the number of years old your account is. Earn 200 rep, you will have 1 Yearling badge, even if your acct is 10 years old. Earn 400 more rep suddenly after 10 years, you will now have 3 Yearling badges, etc.